# Remove duplicate word sentence

Tags: duplicates, notepad++

I have a list of sentences.

I want to deal with duplicates like this:

- White shoes women
- Shoes women white
- Women white shoes

I want to make into this:

- White shoes women

Can I do this in Notepad++?

Or maybe some other software?

Comment: What are your full set of requirements? How do define a duplicate? What role do uppercase and lowercase letters play? How do you choose which of the 'duplicates' is to be kept and which to be discarded?

Comment: How can i say, Like the example 3 line with duplicate word but in different position. so i want to kept the first appeared, and discard other line with same word. No need with uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: No need means what? That we ignore case? So is it fine for the output to be 'white shoes women' or 'WHITE SHOES WOMEN' regardless of input?

Comment: Yes, i mean like that, ignore uppercase and lowercase

Comment: Excellent. So next is it vital that the first sentence encountered be returned? Or is it enough that a sentence containing all the words is returned. Would 'shoes white women' be an acceptable output?

Comment: Yes, 'shoes white women' is acceptable. Just want to kept the first appeared sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do such job in Npp.

Here is a way to do the job with perl that keeps the case and order of first line.
(Thanks to @jwpfox for input example).

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $prev = '';
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $str = join'',sort split' ',lc$_;
    say $_ if $str ne $prev;
    $prev = $str;
}

__DATA__
White shoes women
Shoes women white
Women white shoes
White shoes women
Shoes women white
Women white shoes
Men black boots
Black boots men
Boots men black
girl yellow shirt
yellow girl shirt
pants blue boy
```

**Output:**

```
White shoes women
Men black boots
girl yellow shirt
pants blue boy
```

A version in PHP:

```
$s = array(
'White shoes women',
'Shoes women white',
'Women white shoes',
'White shoes women',
'Shoes women white',
'Women white shoes',
'Men black boots',
'Black boots men',
'Boots men black',
'girl yellow shirt',
'yellow girl shirt',
'pants blue boy');

$prev = '';
foreach($s as $line) {
    $list = explode(' ', strtolower($line));
    sort($list);
    $str = implode('',$list);
    if ($str != $prev) echo $line,"\n";
    $prev = $str;
}
```

**Output:**

```
White shoes women
Men black boots
girl yellow shirt
pants blue boy
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "some other software" option.

Contents of `input.txt` file:

```
White shoes women
Shoes women white
Women white shoes
Men black boots
Black boots men
Boots men black
girl yellow shirt
yellow girl shirt
pants blue boy
```

Python 3:

```
sentences = []

with open('input.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        wordlist = line.split(' ')
        words = []
        for word in wordlist:
            word = word.strip()
            words.append(word.lower())

        words.sort()

        if words not in sentences:
            sentences.append(words)

with open('output.txt', mode='w') as outfile:
    for sentence in sentences:
        for word in sentence:
            outfile.write(word + ' ')
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Contents of `output.txt` file:

```
shoes white women 
black boots men 
girl shirt yellow 
blue boy pants
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. That's what i want to do. But is there any simple tutorial to execute that, I'm not familiar with phyton. Or is that possible if do in php, maybe? I really appreciate your help. Thank's again.

Comment: I can't help with PHP, sorry. If you want to install Python to run the above code then here's a link to instructions https://www.python.org/downloads/. Looks like the Perl option was more to your taste which is 100% fine.